# Mutiple RDP connections in Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008

I am having windows server 2008 R2 Operating System.
I want 5 concurrent users to access this server machine.Currently it supports only two concurrent users.If third wants to connects on server machine one of the two connected users session has to be terminated.
 Is there any way which will help in granting access to 5 concurrent users.

Comment: Offtopic, not a programming question. But yes, you need to configure the server to be a terminal server, plus installing appropriate licensing for that role.

Answer (score 2):

You need to install the Terminal Services Role in order to take the terminal services out of administration mode.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754288(v=ws.10).aspx

Answer (score 2):

Just a brief note on terminology: since we are talking about Server 2008 R2 the role which should be added called Remote Desktop Services (formerly known as Terminal Services)